# How to place a shape in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, window, shapes

I can create a shape using the .create method but I want to know how I can place it in a certain place on the window... I've tried using .pack() but it comes up with an error... Please help.

e.g.

```
circle = canvas.create_oval(5, 5, 40, 40, outline="blue",
                fill="green", width=2)
```

now I need to place circle in a certain place on  the window (.pack() does not work)

Answer (score 2):

`create_oval` is used to create **and** place the oval. `create_oval(5, 5, 40, 40)` will create your circle inside a "box" where `(5,5)` and `(40,40)` are the coordinates of the diagonal's rectangle where the circle will be drawn. The same way a rectangle is drawn.

[image]

Edit: if you have `x_radius` and `y_radius`, you can do something like:

```
create_oval(x-x_radius,y-y_radius,x+x_radius,y+y_radius)
```

to get the size of the canvas, if you haven't instanciated it with a known size (e.g. `canvas=Canvas(self.something, width='700', height='400')`, you can use `.cget(property)`: `x=int(canvas.cget('width'))/2` and `y=int(canvas.cget('height'))/2` will be in the middle.

See [this tutorial](http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_canvas.php).

Comment: But I want to make the circle the same size but position it in the centre of the window...

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Thank btw for your help! :)

Comment: I've found a way round it now... THANK YOU :)

Comment: @user3262355, you are right, cget returns a string. I will correct my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Modified from http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm (which should be your first stop for all Tkinter issues):

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

#Create the canvas and pack it
w = Canvas(master, width=200, height=100)
w.pack()

#These will automatically be drawn on the already packed canvas
w.create_line(0, 0, 200, 100)
w.create_line(0, 100, 200, 0, fill="red", dash=(4, 4))
w.create_oval(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="blue")

mainloop()
```