# How to move a shape while retaining original size in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to have the rectangle I create spawn at the bottom of my tkinter canvas instead of spawning at the top without affecting its size. I have only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22760200/how-to-place-a-shape-in-tkinter) post and this doesn't help me as it does not describe how to move the shape to the bottom of the canvas

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

#Temporary
width = 1024
height=768


class GFG:
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        self.master = master
        self.master.configure(bg="black") #Apart from the canvas colour
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.canvas = Canvas(master, background="black", highlightthickness=0, width=width, height=height) #Canvas colour
        self.rectangle = self.canvas.create_rectangle(5, 5, 25, 25, fill='white')
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.movement()

   def movement(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.rectangle, self.x, self.y)
        self.canvas.after(100, self.movement)

   def left(self, event):
        print(event.keysym)
        self.x = -5
        self.y = 0

   def right(self, event):
       print(event.keysym)
       self.x = 5
       self.y = 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
   master = Tk()
   master.title("Black Hole Settlers")
   gfg = GFG(master)

master.bind("<KeyPress-Left>", lambda e: gfg.left(e))
master.bind("<KeyPress-Right>", lambda e: gfg.right(e))

mainloop()
```

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/DPdhQbqM)

Thanks,

[swanserquack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16336201/swanserquack)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. The square created by your code already moves without changing its size. Though, it's at the top rather than bottom.

Comment: @BryanOakley I am trying to create the square at the bottom of the canvas without changing its size. Thanks for pointing out that it's unclear and I'll edit it now

Comment: Have you tried simply changing the coordinates?

Comment: As you know the height of the canvas, it is just simple maths to calculate the required y-coordinate.

Comment: @BryanOakley Turn's out I'm just an idiot and didn't remember how to move a shape around. I just settled on moving the shape directly after it is made. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Can you please write down your solution? So anyone in the future who stumble upon your question will know what you've missed

Comment: My solution was just adding self.canvas.move(self.rectangle, 512, 690) to the next line to move the rectangle to the desired spot.